# How to get users based on multiple whereHas Condition Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get users based on multiple whereHas condition. First I am getting user with specific role after that I want to sort that users with other whereHas Condition. I have tried some snippets But I am getting all the users with different roles.

my model

```
  public function document()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserDocument::class,'user_id');
    }
    public function portfolios()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Portfolio::class,'user_id');
    }
```

controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $data = User::whereHas("roles", function($q)
        { 
            $q->where("name", "Seller");
        })
        ->whereHas('portfolios',function($q){
            $q->where('status','Pending');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('document',function($s){
            $s->where('status','Pending');
        })
        ->get();
        
        dd($data);
        return view('admin.pendingapproval.index');
    }
```

I am not understanding how to do this. Please help me

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using 'or' in your where has, so you will get the user if it has a Seller role
**or** it has portfolios status is Pending **or** it has a document with status Pending

you should do it like:

```
  $data = User::whereHas("roles", function ($q) {
        $q->where("name", "Seller");
    })
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('portfolios', function ($q) {
                $q->where('status', 'Pending');
            })->orWhereHas('document', function ($s) {
                $s->where('status', 'Pending');
            });
        })->get();
```

now you get the users where has a role 'Seller'
**and** he has Pending portfolios **or** Pending document